Using only numpy functions to create [f0(X,Y),\ldots,fN(X,Y)] without for loops
Suppose that I have n functions f1,...,fn where each function takes two numpy ndarrays X,Y of the same size and returns an ndarray Z of the same size. Is there a way to create the ndarray [f1(X,Y),...,fn(X,Y)] without using for loops or list comprehension?
One can do
import numpy as np

F = [f1,f2,...,fn] # list of n functions
X = np.zeros(M,N)
Y = np.zeros(X.shape)
Z = np.concatenate([f(X,Y) for f in F])

but then I used the loop [f(X,Y) for f in F]. I also though about creating the following function:
def F(i,X,Y):
    """
    Returns fi(X,Y)
    """
    return ...

and then use somthing like np.fromfunction() but I can't figure out how.
The functions fi can be for example fi(X,Y)=X*Y**i, so there is no dependency between them and they can be executed in parallel.

Does each fi have to be called separately (individually)?  'removing loops' in numpy really means 'doing loops in fast compiled code'..  There's no utility in numpy to compile python functions.

@hpaulj The function fi can be for example fi(X,Y)=X*Y**i so there is no dependency between them and they can be executed in parallel, though I'm not sure I understood your question.

@hpaulj with regards to your second point, I'm aware of this. However, I'm planning on writing this code using NumPy only since in a next step I will translate it to CuPy to see if I get speedups.

Do you have to call f1(x,y) and f10(x,y) individually?  numpy doesn't do parallel exectutions; it's relative speed comes from compiled code, as opposed to the interpreted Python.  On the other hand if you can write X*Y**i where i is an array (as opposed to a scalar value), you can avoid python-level loops.

Using the example f(X, Y) = X*Y**i:
import numpy as np
K, M, N = 3, 4, 5
i = np.arange(K)
X = np.zeros((M, N))
Y = np.zeros(X.shape)
Z = X*Y**i.reshape((K, 1, 1))
Z.shape  # (3, 4, 5)

The key part is reshaping i to be orthogonal to the two axes of X and Y. NumPy uses broadcasting to treat all arrays as though they had the same broadcasted shape (K, M, N), effectively computing your function for each combination of the elements of i and X/Y.
You can do this with any function that is fully vectorized to compute results elementwise. If your function is not vectorized (i.e. if it only works for scalar inputs), you can use np.vectorize to vectorize it appropriately.
def f_scalar(i, x, y):
    assert np.shape(i) == ()
    assert np.shape(x) == ()
    assert np.shape(y) == ()
    return x*y**i

f = np.vectorize(f_scalar)
Z = f(i.reshape((K, 1, 1)), X, Y)
Z.shape

Note, however, that the np.vectorize approach will rarely be much faster than for loops; it is just more convenient to use.
